# Extend HTML header semantic element class

Tags: javascript, html

Does the HTML Header semantic element has a class that can be extended to create a custom header?

Can't find any semantic HTML element class here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API

I would like to create a custom component like explained here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml

Comment: Have you tried `class MyHeader extends HTMLElement` and then registering using `customElements.define('my-header', MyHeader, { extends: 'header' });` and using it like `<header is="my-header"></header>`? According to the spec, I'd find it reasonable if that was the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: @connexo You are right, it actually says: `The required third parameter tells the browser which tag you're extending. This is necessary because many HTML tags share the same DOM interface.` When I do this, do I have to use the `is=xxxxx` or can I just use `<my-elem></my-elem>`?

Comment: You have to use the `is` syntax (otherwise your wish for semantics would be lost anyway, so that's the whole point!). There is no such thing as semantic *classes*, only semantic *tags*. Semantics is only about the markup.